# How to add proxy repositories on nexus?

Tags: spring, maven, nexus

To use matt of org.eclipse.paho, I want to add repo.spring.io in my nexus as proxy repository.However, "remote automatically blocked" every time.

Comment: You might need to define proxy settings for the repository or the server in general.

Answer (score 0):

Repositories in Nexus are auto-blocked if Nexus is unable to reach the remote.  Check the nexus.log, there will be a log message indicating why the remote could not be reached.